# For some reason webserver won't listen

Tags: node.js, web, server

so I have webServer.js and package.json inside webServer folder and for some reason webserver won't listen when i call it in cmd with node webServer.js

this is my webServer

```
var http = require('http');


http.createServer(function(req, res){
console.log(req);
console.log("***********************************");
console.log("***********************************");
console.log("***********************************");
console.log("***********************************");
console.log("***********************************");
console.log("***********************************");
console.log("***********************************");
console.log("***********************************");
console.log("***********************************");
console.log(req.url);
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : 'text/html'});
res.write('hello world');
res.end();
}).listen(80);
```

and this is package.json

```
{
  "name": "webserver",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "webSever.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

This is what I get when I type in cmd node webServer.js:https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkxNz.jpg

and this is what happens when I type localhost/80 in browser
infinite loading: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7rrH.jpg

Comment: Should be `localhost:80` or just `localhost`, not `localhost/80`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use different port numbers like 3000, 5000 etc.

Port 80 is reserved by the system!

[See details on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers)